# How to use select method in form_for in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I would like to use a select method in form_for in Rails.  I'm not quite sure how to do it.  Could anyone point me to an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you talking about `select` or `select_tag` or `collection_select`?

```
# advanced users only
= f.select :field_id, options_for_select(Model.collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]})

# easiest, assuming you have a model
= f.collection_select :field_id, Model.all, :id, :name

# without model
= select_tag 'model[field_id]', @model.field_id, options_for_select(Model.collect{|m| [m.name, m.id]})
```

Comment: Since he's using form_for, I would guess select is the right one. The documentation for it is here (You just don't pass it the object as the first argument since it's inferred by the form object): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

Comment: Thanks!  The part about not passing the first object is what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Model.all.collect" for the first example?